# Ignore versioned files

Tags: tortoisesvn

My team lead just checked in every file under the sun.  I have to pick and choose my battles, so if there's a way I could just ignore these files and show the other programmers how to do the same I would highly prefer that to arguing with him about removing the files from the repository.

Unfortunately, I just read the docs that say I can't ignore versioned files.  Anyone aware of any kind of workaround that will let me do it anyway?

Comment: Have you tried changlelists? The files will still be updated, but at least you'll not see them marked in the Commit window all times.

Comment: Thanks @CiganoMorrisonMendez.  Thankfully that team lead resigned after getting a horrible 3 month review (and I moved on to another opportunity shortly after that anyway).  I'll keep this in mind should I ever be put under another lead who was hired for his schooling and fluffy looking resume rather than any relevant experience.